# JSF 1.1 equivalent of f:event

Tags: jsf

I am trying to re-retrieve data from my database whenever the user clicks on a link (just in case any information has changed)

But I am using JSF 1.1,

In JSF 2.0 we have

```
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{refreshDataTable}"> </f:event>
        </f:metadata>
```

or even PhaseListeners, but in 1.1 we don't.

Does anyone know an equivalent, or anything that can invoke an action on a bean when a link is clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the bean in the request scope and do the job in its constructor.

Don't put the bean in the session scope. That's only bad for user experience and server memory. If you want to simulate the view scope in JSF 1.x, have a look at Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>` or RichFaces' `<a4j:keepAlive>`.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is if i put it in request scope, then I lose alot of other data. I want to keep all of the original data, but only refresh the data table.

Comment: Use `<t:saveState>` then. I by the way assume that you're talking about GET links, not POST links.

Comment: Add `<t:saveState value="#{bean}" />` to the view wherein you'd like to simulate the JSF 2 view scope on the given request scoped bean. As long as you return `null` or `void` from action methods, the bean will live as long as you interact with the same view.

Comment: good call, i forgot about the a4j:keepAlive by rich:faces. Since i'm already using the rich:faces framework i'll just have to use that and switch to a request scope. Thanks

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html is a great reference too.